# rails mongo query to get previous day's results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am generating a report from my ruby on rails app that would run everyday at 7 in the morning.
This report would collect the results from the previous day.

So basically I want query previous day's results to my Mongo collection. This is what I am tried:

```
logs = Log.where(:comp => comp, :created_at => (Date.today -1))
```

I got the following error:

```
BSON::InvalidDocument: Date is not currently supported; use a UTC Time instance instead.
```

What is the best approach to get the aboce result:

This is the the format of my date in my db:

```
 "created_at" : ISODate("2015-12-02T23:12:38.076Z")
```

Comment: actually, I can't reproduce this - what version of mongoid/rails/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in mongoid:

```
logs = Log.where(:comp => comp, :created_at.gte => (Date.today -1 ).to_datetime)
```

`Date.to_datetime` will default to midnight as shown here:

```
(Date.today - 1).to_datetime
=> Wed, 30 Mar 2016 00:00:00 +0000
```